# Copy path from meld window

Tags: 16.04, meld

When viewing files in `meld` I sometimes need to copy the path of a file. In 14.04 and earlier the file names were shown as text fields where I could easily copy the path from.

In 16.04 the text field has been replaced with a widget used for loading a file. So I can no longer copy the path like I used to.

How can I copy the path of a file I am viewing in `meld` in 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded Meld to 1.5.3 with the following actions:

```
sudo wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/meld/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb -O /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1_all.deb 
sudo apt-get install -f

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-meld
Package: meld
Pin: version 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

It works better for me. It has for example very useful `<Ctrl+Shift+R>` shortcut and close with `<Ctrl+Q>`. Also you can copy file paths with it.

Comment: Installing the package that way sounds like a huge security risk. This does no validation of the integrity of the downloaded package.

Comment: @kasperd You are right, but I can't use newer version of Meld because of well-formed (shortcut) habbits and better usability of previous version :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another (still not too convenient) way to copy path is to click on the widget, use a context menu of "Open file" dialog.

[image]

Reasons, why a convenient text field has been replaced by these buttons, are explained [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=746616). I'm also going to rollback to a latest usable version of `meld`: 1.8.6.